# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key '...'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make a dropdownlist which shows every category id and name. Unfortunately when i start, it shows the following error: 
"There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key '...'."

In the view:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Zoekitem

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@Html.DropDownList("list1", ViewBag.categorieBag as SelectList, "-- Select --")
```

In the controller:

```
FAQDBConnection FAQconnection = new FAQDBConnection();
var getlist = FAQconnection.Categorie.ToList();
SelectList list = new SelectList(getlist, "ID", "Naam");
ViewBag.categorieBag = list;
```

In the model:

```
public class Categorie
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Naam { get; set; }
    }

    public class FAQDBConnection : DbContext
    {
        public FAQDBConnection()
        : base("FAQDBConnection")
        {
            //disable initializer
            Database.SetInitializer<FAQDBConnection>(null);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
        public DbSet<Categorie> Categorie { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Zoekitem> Zoekitem { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ZoekitemCategorie> ZoekitemCategorie { get; set; }
    }
```

Every single time i start the program, it says that there is no viewdata of the first string given in the dropdownlist. In this case: "list1".

Just so you know, the `@model WebApplication1.Models.Zoekitem` is there for the some other textboxes included for the create page.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after speaking to a colleague about it, we managed to solve the problem.

In my SQL database I had a third table, this one was meant to pair the id's from two other tables.
In our controller we had the code in the POST action method, this had to be in the GET action method.
Also in our model we didn't define our keys. Keep note that defining our keys as in `[Key]` didn't do the trick on its own. `[Column(Order = 0)]` and `[Column(Order = 1)]` had to be added to define which one is more important.

Controller:

```
// GET: Zoekitem/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        FAQDBConnection FAQconnection = new FAQDBConnection();
        var getlist = FAQconnection.Categorie.ToList();
        SelectList list = new SelectList(getlist, "ID", "Naam");
        ViewBag.categorieBag = list;

        return View();
    }

    // POST: Zoekitem/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Zoekitem zoekitem, string catID, string catNaam)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Zoekitem.Add(zoekitem);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

        return View(db.Categorie.ToList());
    }
```

Model:

```
public class ZoekitemCategorie
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int IDZ { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int IDC { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("list1", ViewBag.categorieBag as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "-- Select --")
```

(Feel free to correct me on mistakes!)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace as SelectedList with `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

```
@Html.DropDownList("list1", ViewBag.categorieBag as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "-- Select --")
```

Comment: Unfortunately i still get the same error: "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'list1'."